# File->New->Android Project->Create Project From Existing Code AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: android

I am trying to look at Android examples from Apress and Wiley's books.
Errors occur when looking at code from both companies.
ie. Apress Beginning Android http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/584/

Extracted Chapter7 to `Z:\new\Chapter7`

FYI Android SDK location `Z:\eclipse\Android\android-sdk`

File->New->Android Project->Create Project From Existing Code
Selected `Z:\new\Chapter7`
Build Target Android 2.2

AM able to get HelloWorld and applications typed in to work with current Eclipse setup to run on hardware and simulators, but when attempting to look at others sorce code am getting errors.

When opening source code from either companies books I get similar errors

```
[2011-07-27 02:26:41 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read Z:\eclipse\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\eclipse\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2011-07-27 02:26:41 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read Z:\eclipse\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\eclipse\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2011-07-27 02:26:45 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read Z:\new\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\new\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2011-07-27 02:30:41 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read Z:\new\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\new\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is trying to create projects from folders `Z:\new\` and `Z:\eclipse\Android\android\samples\android-8`, which I can assure you is wrong. Is there another project you are making in which you are creating from those two paths? I know for a fact that `Z:\eclipse\Android\android\samples\android-8` has multiple projects inside and you need to specify the exact project.

For instance, inside `android-8`, I see that there is `ApiDemos` and `BackupRestore`, you need to select those in order for Eclipse to find the AndroidManifest.xml files.

As for the other link (`Z:\new\`), make sure you have selected `Z:\new\Chapter7`, it looks like you didn't do that. it's looking in the `\new\` folder for the `AndroidManifest.xml` when it should be looking in `\new\Chapter7`.